# Publicly Held Shares versus Float. Are they the same?

Tags: stocks, investing

According to Investopedia and finance.zacks.com, Stock Float is defined as number of outstanding shares minus closely-held shares (Company officers, directors may be long-term holders; or restricted shares that have restrictions on stock sales). And, Float is the number of shares practically available for trading.

On the other hand, NYSE and Nasdad listing standards mention Publicly Held Shares as Outstanding Shares excluding shares held by directors, officers, and their immediate family members, and other concentrated holdings of 10% or more.

I'm wondering which number is smaller, Publicly Held Shares or Float? ,or are they the same?

Because those concentrated holdings of 10% plus are still available for trading; so, they should be a part of Float. My thought is that Float is the bigger number, but I'm not sure.